# Showing there does not exist any strict increasing composites at all

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose we have two function:

\begin{equation} f(x_1,x_2)= \begin{cases} x_1 x_2  & \text{ if }\;\;x_1x_2 < 4\\
4 &\text{ if }\;\; 4 \leq x_1 x_2 < 8\\
x_1 x_2 &\text{ if }\;\; x_1 x_2 \geq 8 \end{cases}\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation} u(x_1,x_2)= \begin{cases} x_1 x_2 &  \text{ if }\;\;x_1x_2 < 4\\
4 &\text{ if }\;\; x_1 x_2=4 \text{ and } x_1 \geq x_2 \\
5& \text{   if }\;\; x_1 x_2=4 \text{ and } x_1 < x_2\\
x_1 x_2 +1& \text{ if }\;\; x_1 x_2 \geq 8 \end{cases}\end{equation}

How would we in this case prove that there is no strictly increasing function
$v: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_1,x_2) = v(u(x_1,x_2))$?

Can simply stating that \begin{equation} v(y) = \begin{cases} y \hspace{3cm} \forall y \in[0,4]\\
4 \hspace{3cm} \forall y \in[4,8)\\
y-1 \hspace{3cm} \forall y \geq 8  \end{cases}\end{equation}

be sufficient? Or should we attempt to show by contradiction that there does not exist any strictly increasing function v at all?

Comment: What does the $x$ stand for in the definition of $f$ and $u$ which do not have $x$ as variable?

Comment: I deleted the earlier comments, as promised, but I'm still wondering if you meant to leave $u(x_1,x_2)$ undefined when $4\lt x_1x_2\lt8$.  (Oh, and I think you mean $u(x_1,x_2)=x_1x_2$ if $x_1x_2\lt4$, not $x_1x_2\le4$, since otherwise $u(1,4)$ is both $4$ and $5$.)

Comment: yep! It should be right this time.

Comment: You've still left $u(x_1,x_2)$ undefined when $4\lt x_1x_2\le8$.  In your definition, do you really mean to say "if $4\le x_1x_2\lt8$ instead of "if $x_1x_2=4$"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has $f(2,2)=u(2,2)=4$. From the condition
$$f(x_1,x_2)\equiv v\bigl(u(x_1,x_2)\bigr)\tag{1}$$
it then follows that necessarily $v(4)=4$. Since $v$ has to be strictly increasing this would imply $v(5)>4$. But then
$$v\bigl(u(1,4)\bigr)=v(5)>4=f(1,4)\ ,$$
which contradicts $(1)$.